# Is my server safe from remote hackers if I only allow 1 port and 1 service behind it which only hashs incoming bytes stream & send the hash key back?

Tags: linux, ports

I have a python script ,which accepts an incoming connection, reads from the byte stream ,hash it (I'm pretty sure the hash function itself can't be exploited) ,sends the hash key back ,then closes the connection .

Is my server secure (by secure I mean the data on my server is not leaked ,doesn't have to be serving 7x24 under attacks ),if I only allow the port my script is listening to (say 30000) and ban all other ports ?

Nothing except the operating system (in this case ,ubuntu )and the python script mentioned above is running on this machine .I don't use this machine to do anything other than this (like browsing web pages etc ,I don't do it on this machine ).

Comment: "secure" from what? Closing ports does not make a server "secure". It just prevents traffic to those closed ports.

Comment: "I have a gun that only has one bullet. Could it be used to accidentally kill someone?" -- uh, yes. The problem is not how simple the script is, but how secure it is and how you use it. Please read the duplicate and consider my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

No. The question is not the number of open ports but which services are behind these ports and the security of these services. Thus, it is sufficient for an attacker if there is only one open port which one service but this service is exploitable.

Comment: My service is a python script ,which accepts an incoming connection, reads and hashs the bytes stream ,then send it back ,is it secure ?

Comment: @iouvxz: It is easy to write a script which does what you write and is still exploitable. It is impossible to say just based on this description if your script is exploitable or not.

Comment: So the only exploitable part is the flaws in this script ,is that what you mean ?

Comment: I'm sure this script can't be exploited .My only concern is can anyone hack into my server the steal the source code of this hash function . If they reverse engineered the hash function ,it can't be helped .

Comment: Say ,can they hack into  my computer if the script just accept the incoming bytes stream , ignores it ,then send "hello world" back ?

Comment: Sorry never mind ,I figured it out my self .Thanks any way .

Comment: If by "secure" in your question you mean from people gaining unauthorised access to your server (you should mention that), then yes, your script could be used by someone to hack into your server. How do I know? Because you are sure that it can't be exploited. The duplicate goes into that, too. Also, the firewall might end up with a vulnerability tthat could be exploited.